# Mininet CLI output redirect

Tags: mininet

I am running a custom topology in Mininet and would like to get bandwidth between each switch. When I try Iperf s1 s2, I get the results which is good.

Now I want the output to redirected to a file. I am aware of running the command inside the host, but I am trying it from Mininet CLI. Please advise on this.